# Excel download - Laravel 5.1

Tags: excel, export, laravel-5.1, maatwebsite-excel

I am using eloquent query with three tables called invoice,invoiceduedates,payments.So all the data i am exporting to excel by using the below query in laravel.

```
$pay=Invoice::with('invoiceduedates','payments')->where('Eventcode','=',$eventcode)->get();
$payment='';$invoicepay=array();
foreach($pay as $payble){
            $x=0;$due='';$payment='';$i=0;
            foreach($payble->invoiceduedates as $duedate){
                        $x++;
                        $due .= $duedate->date.','.$duedate->amount;
                        if($x <= count($payble->invoiceduedates)-1){
                        $due.=",";
                        }


            }

            foreach($payble->payments as $paydate){
                        $i++;
                        $payment .= $paydate->adjust_mode.','.$paydate->recieved_amount;
                        if($i <= count($payble->payments)-1){
                        $payment.=",";
                        }


            }

            $invoicepay[]= array_merge(explode(',',$due),explode(',',$payment));
            unset($due);unset($payment);unset($i);unset($x);
}
$export = json_decode(json_encode((array) $invoicepay), true);

          Excel::create('Data', function($excel) use ($export)
             {
                $excel->sheet('Inovice Data', function($sheet) use ($export)
                {
                    $sheet->fromArray($export);

                    $sheet->cells('A1:AE1', function($cells)
                     {

                                $cells->setBackground('#000000');
                                $cells->setFontColor('#fff');

                    });
                    $sheet->row(1, array(
                        'Due Date1','Due Amount1','Due Date2','Due Amount2','AdjustMode1','Rcv Amount1','AdjustMode2','Rcv Amount2'

                     ));
                });
})->download('xlsx');
```

Below is my excel results:

```
| Due Date1  | Due Amount1 | Due Date2             | Due Amount2 | AdjustMode1           | Rcv Amount1 | AdjustMode2           | Rcv Amount2 |
|------------|-------------|-----------------------|-------------|-----------------------|-------------|-----------------------|-------------|
| 2016-03-25 | 2000        | 2016-02-29            | 2000        | Overseas Bank Charges | 2000        | Overseas Bank Charges | 2743        |
| 2016-03-31 | 3750        | Overseas Bank Charges | 3708        | Overseas Bank Charges | 2750        |                       |             |
```

But whats happening here is when there is no second  due dates in invoiceduedates table the columns of Due Date2, Due Amount2 are getting overlapped with Adjust Mode1 and RCV Amount1.

The Actual excel how i want is below

```
| Due Date1  | Due Amount1 | Due Date2  | Due Amount2 | AdjustMode1           | Rcv Amount1 | AdjustMode2           | Rcv Amount2 |
|------------|-------------|------------|-------------|-----------------------|-------------|-----------------------|-------------|
| 2016-03-25 | 2000        | 2016-02-29 | 2000        | Overseas Bank Charges | 2000        | Overseas Bank Charges | 2743        |
| 2016-03-31 | 3750        |            |             | Overseas Bank Charges | 3708        | Overseas Bank Charges | 2750        |
```

Ya when there is no second due date i want those columns to be empty.How can i control that in foreach loop or in header part of excel? Please help .

Thank you.

Comment: Does your `$export` contain empty column?

Comment: @weigreen no it does not have because i m storing data in multiple rows in both the tables.

Comment: Does your `$duedate` and `$paydate` will have at most two row?

Comment: It depends .But one row will be there for sure for $duedate and $paydate. or sometimes $duedate will be having one row $paydate will be having two rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you didn't give `$export` empty space

So maatwebsite-excel's ->fromArray() function will put data into excel **one by one**

These code can fix your problem:(part of your code)

```
        $x=0;$due='';$payment='';$i=0;
        foreach($payble->invoiceduedates as $duedate){
                    $x++;
                    $due .= $duedate->date.','.$duedate->amount;
                    if($x <= count($payble->invoiceduedates)-1){
                    $due.=",";
                    }


        }
        //added
        if($x == 1){
            $due.=",,"; //add two empty column for  Due Date2 & Due Amount2
        }

        foreach($payble->payments as $paydate){
                    $i++;
                    $payment .= $paydate->adjust_mode.','.$paydate->recieved_amount;
                    if($i <= count($payble->payments)-1){
                    $payment.=",";
                    }


        }
        //added
        if($i == 1){
            $payment.=",,"; //add two empty column for  AdjustMode2 & Rcv Amount2
        }
```

Comment: I have another doubt what if there are three duedates how to give the condition dynamically in if loop ..

Comment: This will be more complex, if you have three duedates, you will also need to change your Excel's first row. Does your data will have this scenario?

Comment: Ya it has the same scenario ..we never know howmany duedates and paydates will be there it depends on the persons actually..i have to think beyond this and want to handle this in future aspects too...how can i give dynamic if loop ? will that be done ?

Comment: And one more thing i want to change the excel first row as per the data ? can you give me idea how to do that ?